# ASP.NET web-service with multiple parameters HttpPut

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post, webservice-client, http-post-vars

I am trying to insert values in my database using `HttpPut` but I can't get it to work for multiple parameters.

```
// PUT: api/Orders/CustomerID/TableID
[HttpPut("{CustomerID,TableID}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutOrder([FromRoute] string CustomerID, [FromRoute] string TableID)
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            string s = "INSERT INTO orders (CustomerID, TableID) VALUES (@CustomerID, @TableID)";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(s, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", CustomerID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableID", TableID);
            connection.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        { }
        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: `I can't get it to work` What exactly is happening?

Comment: At the moment I am getting 502 Bad Gateway when trying to run the PUT /api/orders/tom/5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out what I was doing wrong.

```
[HttpPut("{CustomerID}/{TableID}")]
public void PutOrder([FromRoute] string CustomerID, [FromRoute] string TableID)
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            string s = "INSERT INTO orders (CustomerID, TableID) VALUES (@CustomerID, @TableID)";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(s, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", CustomerID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableID", TableID);
            connection.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
}
```

Adjusted code to this.

I was mistakenly running POST instead of PUT (arrgghgh).

Now it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Define attribute route.

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/Orders/{CustomerID}/{TableID}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutOrder([FromRoute] string CustomerID, [FromRoute] string TableID)
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            string s = "INSERT INTO orders (CustomerID, TableID) VALUES (@CustomerID, @TableID)";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(s, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", CustomerID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableID", TableID);
            connection.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        { }
        return NoContent();
    }
}
```